# Peticion a php con ajax

Tags: php, ajax, peticion

tengo un problema que no he podido resolver, al enviar una peticion desde un pagina web con AJAX la peticion es enviada pero al ejecutarse la rutina en php no ejecuta la funcion porque aparentemente no recibe los datos, y genera un error "Undefined index" en mi archivo php

este es el Select que llama a la funcion

`<select class="selec1" Name="Menu1" id="MenuRub" onchange= "EnviarInfo(2);">`

esta funcion es la que envia los datos

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function EnviarInfo(CodFuncion){
        var MenuRub=document.getElementById("MenuRub");
        var Id=MenuRub.selectedIndex;
        
        var Parametros={
            "CodigoFuncion":CodFuncion,
            "IdAgrupamiento":Id
        };  
        
        $.ajax({
            data:Parametros,
            type:"POST",
            url:"CatalogoProd.php",
            async:false
            
        })
    }
</script>
```

y por ultimo este es el código de mi archivo CatalogoProd.php

```
$Inicio=new CatalogoProductos();

if (isset($_POST)){
    
    switch($_POST["CodigoFuncion"]){
      case 1:
        
        break;
      case 2:
        $DatosRub=$Inicio->ConsultaSeleccionAgrupamiento($_POST["IdAgrupamiento"]);
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
```

el problema es que en el php genera el error Undefined Index;

Comment: Cual es el error completo?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: CodigoFuncion in C:\wamp64\www\CatalogoProd.php on line 8

Comment: y cual es la linea 8 las de $_POST["CodigoFuncion"] o la de IdAgrupamiento? Yo intentaría ver que contenido tiene $_POST cuando es llamada, ahí verás que índices tiene y aislar el error.

Comment: la linea es la $_POST["CodigoFuncion]; para ver si los datos pasaban bien genere unos Alert en la funcion JS, y verifique que si eran correctos, haciendo un var_dump del $_POST, y me arroja que trae una variable que se envío en otra rutina,

Comment: array (size=1)
  'TipoBusqueda' => string '1' (length=1)

Comment: como si no enviara los datos desde ajax

Comment: Creo que no lo envía, dices bien. El objeto Parametros es donde van los datos, y veo que las claves llevan comillas, lo mismo jQuery es un poco tikis mikis, prueba a quitarle las comillas. Y si no te va, pues vainilla Javascript que ese no falla.

Comment: Ya lo haz podido resolver? Prueba a establecer el contenido en los **headers** en la configuración de la petición `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }` y las recibes en **PHP** de esta manera `$post = json_decode($_POST, true)`

Comment: Ademas en las configuraciones de la solicitud **ajax** cambia `type: "POST"` por esto `method: "POST"`

Comment: he probado con las sugerencias pero sigo sin poder resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

he seguido investigando una solucion a mi problema, logre resolverlo modificando las llamadas del proyecto, y en la pagina principal las referencias a al archivo php que carga el select, e esta forma al seleccionar la primer opción creo un nuevo select con las opciones que recupere de la base de datos